# Which Eclipse IDE to use for android development?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to know which Eclipse IDE to use for android development.

The following url http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ shows  a lot of option.

Right now i am using Mac OS X v 10.6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"We recommend the "Eclipse Classic" version. Otherwise, you should use a Java or RCP version of Eclipse." 
<sub>Quote from Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html</sub>

Comment: This page no longer has Eclipse related info.

Comment: "Eclipse Classic" has been renamed to "Eclipse Standard". So you can download "Eclipse Standard" for android development.

Comment: ADT Plugin (UNSUPPORTED)
The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported, as per this announcement in June 2015.
The Eclipse ADT plugin has many known bugs and potential security bugs that will not be fixed.
You should immediately switch to use Android Studio, the official IDE for Android. For help transitioning your projects, read Migrate to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Take the second - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 99 MB

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to Android SDK [requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements).

Looks like Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) or greater is required at the time of this answer. Because you'll be using the ADT Plugin for Eclipse, check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for Eclipse version requirement and other info. The version will probably always match the one stated on the SDK page.

If you decide on Eclipse IDE for Java Developers from the above package, get it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2).